# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 incompatible with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2010

I ran Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant on my laptop today, and I saw something very interesting.  Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is not compatible with Windows 8, but Visual Studio 2010 (no service pack) is compatible.
Does Visual Studio 2010 SP1 work on Windows 8?  If not, are there just a few specific functions that do not work correctly, or does it just crash and burn and become unusable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compatibilty Center listed out that Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is not compatible with Windows 8. But Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1, Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1, Visual Studio 2010 Premium SP1 are compatible with Windows 8.

Which version of Visual Studio you are using?

Visit the Compatibility Center for more details about application compatibility.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/ProductViewerWithDefaultFilters?TempOsid=win8&Locale=en-us&TextSearch=Visual%2BStudio%2B2010%2BSP1&Type=Both&CurrentPage=0&TotalPages=1&ShowCriteria=0&SortCriteria=Relevance&Compatibility=Unknown&LastRequested=14

Comment: I have a copy of Ultimate, but the upgrade assistant just lists it as the general service pack.  Do I have to install the Ultimate-specific one to make it compatible?

Comment: The SP1 installer will automatically install itself for the right version of Visual Studio 2010. There is nothing you have to do to get it to work. I've been running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 on my Windows 8 laptop since the launch of Windows 8 and have yet to encounter any problems.

Comment: The SP1 installer doesn't work for me on Windows 8.  It says that it can't find an installation of Visual Studio, but VS is installed.  How can I get this to install?

Comment: For me, on Windows 8, the Windows Update SP1 installer failed. Fortunately, downloading the SP1 ISO from MSDN subscriptions, I was able to run its setup.exe and install.