# Can i upgrade to Windows 8 and still have Visual Studio 2010 Professional work?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, virtual-machine

I am trying to upgrade a VM that has Windows 7 on it and upgrade to WIndows 8.  At the start of the upgrade process it highlights that Visual Studio 2010 is not compatible.  Is this true?  I was really shocked that VS 2010 is not upgradable onto Windows 8.  I guess I will stay with Windows 7 for now but I wanted to find out if there is some patch or something that will allow me to use VS 2010 on my Windows 8 upgrade.

I see [this other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170054/visual-studio-2010-sp1-incompatible-with-windows-8) but its a slightly different question and doesn't really answer the question around why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [Microsoft Connect Website](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/769074/visual-studio-2010-incompatible-with-windows-8) it states there is an incompatibility with VS2010 primarily with the Test Tools.

From above Link:

> Hi there - VS 2010 does indeed have an incompatibility with Win8 - The scenario for the incompatibility was around the test tools so in general VS 2010 will run after install on Win8 - This issue was addressed in this GDR (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736182).

They suggest running the Update http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736182 the article also gives a little more insight to what the issues are.

Comment: should you run the upgrade before or after upgrading to windows 8?

Comment: @leora The update says it is compatible with Windows7 and Windows8. I really do not know the answer since I haven't tried installing it on Windows8 or upgrading a Windows 7 instance. I probably would install the update first then see where it goes from there.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually tried it myself, but most Windows 7 apps work just fine in Windows 8, and I couldn't think of a reason why VS2010 wouldn't work.  You can try making a copy of your VM and upgrading that just to be safe.

Comment: but it specifically says, not compatible when you go through the upgrade process

Answer (score 0):

I'm running VS2010 on Windows 8. It works just fine.

Comment: do you know why the upgrade process flags it as not compatible

Comment: @Leora - It appears to be the test tools, per the answer by Mark Hall

Comment: @chuex How did you get this to work, i have been trying all day. I installed VS2010, SP1 and even the GDR pack win win 8.1 clean install and still when i search for it, i can see it?

Comment: @Komengem Well, you are using 8.1. I have not tested VS2010 with that version of the OS. Having said that VS2010 does *not* show up on the Start screen under Win 8.0. I think I had to create a shortcut to the install location: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe*. The shortcut oddly says the exe is SQL Server Data tools, but when launched it is VS 2010.

Comment: @chuex yes this operating system can be frustrating, but i figured it out after a while. Thanks for a response!